# How to update the Entity Framework after adding new tables in Web Forms?

Tags: entity-framework, webforms

I am enhancing some ASP.NET web forms applications.

I need to add some new tables to the existing application.

After I create the new tables in SQL Server, how I do update the Entity Framework so that entities and relationships are updated in the EDM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open up the .edmx, right-click in some empty space, and select 'update model from database'.